# detect if transaction fails and is rerun with objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, objectify

I am using objectify as an interface to the GAE datastore and am wondering how I can detect when a transaction fails.  That is, when you call

```
ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
    public void vrun() {
    //save entity, this may throw - concurrent modification exception 
    }
});
```

If an exception is thrown, the vrun() method is called again.  I would like to log when this happens.  I have tried many things - surrounding the contents of vrun() with a try/catch, passing a reference to a boolean flag, etc.  But this does not appear to work.  Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

I need to be able to programmatically detect if the transaction failed , and have some code execute before it is reattempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overload for `transactNew()` that limits the # of tries:

```
ofy().transactNew(1, new VoidWork() {
    ...
});
```

This will let you manage retries on your own. Note that prior to v5.1.6, the # was erroneously being used as a # of retries (not tries). In v5.1.6, behavior was corrected to match the documentation. It's the # of tries.

Comment: Ah I see, i had tried that already but am using an older version of Objectify.  Upgrading to 5.1.6 appears to be giving better results, thanks.